# Cleared all of my cache but still seeing old website

Tags: dns, domain

I have a website setup on a free host called 00webhost. I was previously using a free web host called wink.s. I have a .com domain purchased from 1and1. I had wink.ws's DNS servers pointed to the domain (my .com).

2 days ago I changed the .coms DNS's to the 000webhosts DNS's. For some reason, I still keep seeing the wink.ws one even though my domain isn't pointed to their DNS servers. The thing is, everyone else who accesses the domain can see the new website host (000webhost).

So I figured it was a cache problem. I cleared all my browser cache, ran ccleaner, and flushed DNS in CMD prompt, restarted computer, and still can't get to the new website, it keeps taking me to the old one. I'm honestly out of ideas on what to do.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: win 7 home prem x64

Comment: Does the problem follow your computer or your internet connection or both?  That is, if a friend brought their laptop to your location would they see the issue, or if you took your laptop to a coffee shop, would you still see the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be that the DNS changes haven't yet propagated to the DNS server you are using.

You can try using a different DNS server temporarily until the changes have spread everywhere.

To do this:

- Go to Network Connections in the Control Panel
- Double click on the connection that is being used
- Click Properties
- Double click Internet Protocol Version 4
- Set the new server addresses:

[image: screenshot DNS servers]

The one I have set in my example is one of Google's DNS servers - `8.8.8.8`.

Comment: Note that means anyone on your connection, maybe even on your ISP will have this issue . . . for completeness sake, you should throw a redirect up on your old site . . .

Comment: NP Donavon. Ernie is correct - I put this answer here so that you can quickly access your new website, but be aware that it means that other people may not be able to. You should change the DNS server back to the other one and check every now and then. I'm not sure what sort of redirect Ernie is referring to though, a HTTP redirect probably wouldn't work as it would redirect to the same domain name.

Comment: I was thinking An HTTP redirect to the IP would work, assuming the web server is configured to handle a request via IP . . . if it's a shared server, this may not work, and may just redirect to the hosting companies landing page . . .

Answer (score 1):

Your browser may no longer be caching the old site, but there could be multiple servers between you and the wider web that are erroneously caching the site.

What IP address to you get if you use PING or NSLOOKUP on that domain name? Old or new?

If you want to cheat and avoid (rather than solve) the problem, you can [add an entry to your hosts file](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/), which will force your PC to go to the new server.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same problem before, and it was so annoying to see my page looking horrible. The worse part is that, the `html` and `php` contents will have the new changes applied but files like `css` and `javascript` won't have any changes, but remains at the old state.

**Simple trick to permanently avoid these error is to do something like this:**

instead of applying `style` tag like this `<link href="/sample_style.css">`

Use some server side trike to apply some param. For me, I'll use `PHP` for my sample.

**example** `<link href="/sample_style.css?<?php echo md5(time());?>">` sample output `<link href="/sample_style.css?d1ae421f76277556cf7af464a6ec5761">`

It will force the browser to load the file every time as a new file.

Try it, it works perfectly for me.

Comment: Works also for `js` tags and images

Answer (score 0):

You should understand that DNS too has caching, and that this is probably outside of your control.

Your old DNS record will have had a TTL which says for how long caching DNS servers can keep the old IP address cached. Until that much time has passed, there is no way to force the DNS server you are using to fetch the new address.

(Well, if you control the DNS server, then of course you can force it. But not the other servers in the world which you don't control.)

If you are lucky, you can find a (public?) DNS server which doesn't have the old address cached any longer, and use that. If they never queried your site's address before, there won't be any cached value; or maybe their previous cache already went past the TTL expiration.

You can use `dig` or `nslookup` to see the remaining TTL until your server will query again and fetch a new value; see [*Check remaining TTL for nameserver* on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/363295/check-remaining-ttl-for-nameserver).

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

1. Navigate to the desktop Right-click the Start button (the Windows
   logo in the lower-left)
2. Choose Command Prompt (Admin)
3. When asked whether to allow Command Prompt to make changes to your computer, select Yes
4. Type "ipconfig /flushdns" and press Enter
5. Type "ipconfig /registerdns" and press Enter

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Please take the quick [Tour]https://superuser.com/tour) to learn how StackExchange Q&A sites differ from internet forums. Please also see Answering- and Asking -sections in the [Help](https://superuser.com/help) to learn how things work. I re-formatted the answer to fit better on the site. The answer could be improved by explaining why and how exactly does this help in the situation. See "How do I write a good answer" in Help for more suggestions [From Review](https://superuser.com/review/late-answers/1084444)